# how to generalize bootstrap toggle selection with Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

I am using bootstrap toggle and handling selection in a function. In my application there will be many toggle groups. 
I would like to remove duplication of code and have a common service/factory which will handle toggle selection for `n` number of toggle.

Here is link to my [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/MAhMxtUit38AjUNhxfb7?p=preview).

[image]

You may ask what is the need to handle selection? because based on toggle selection there will be changes in DOM. Some fields may hide/show based on selection.

*Please don't refer to any third party library, help me in understanding the logic, How this can be done.*

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
  <div class="form-group" style="height: 50px;">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">NUMERIC VALUE</label>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-toggle" value="111" ng-class="{active: vm.sharedService.numericValue === '111'}" ng-click="vm.selectNumericValue('111')">
          111
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-toggle" value="222" ng-class="{active: vm.sharedService.numericValue === '222'}" ng-click="vm.selectNumericValue('222')">
          222
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">ALPHABETICAL VALUE</label>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-toggle" ng-class="{active: vm.sharedService.alphaValue === 'AAA'}" ng-click="vm.selectAlphaValue('AAA')">
          AAA
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-toggle" ng-class="{active: vm.sharedService.alphaValue === 'BBB'}" ng-click="vm.selectAlphaValue('BBB')">
          BBB
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-toggle" ng-class="{active: vm.sharedService.alphaValue === 'CCC'}" ng-click="vm.selectAlphaValue('CCC')">
          CCC
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">Mix VALUE</label>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-toggle" ng-class="{active: vm.sharedService.mixValue === 'A1'}" ng-click="vm.selectMixValue('A1')">
          A1
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-toggle" ng-class="{active: vm.sharedService.mixValue === 'B1'}" ng-click="vm.selectMixValue('B1')">
          B1
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-toggle" ng-class="{active: vm.sharedService.mixValue === 'C1'}" ng-click="vm.selectMixValue('C1')">
          C1
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-toggle" ng-class="{active: vm.sharedService.mixValue === 'D1'}" ng-click="vm.selectMixValue('D1')">
          D1
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**JS**

```
 function selectNumericValue(numValue) {
    vm.sharedService.numericValue = numValue;
  }


  function selectAlphaValue(alphaValue) {
    vm.sharedService.alphaValue = alphaValue;
  }

  function selectMixValue(mixValue) {
    vm.sharedService.mixValue = mixValue;
  }
```

Comment: get rid of bootstrap.js and use angular-ui-bootstrap. There are good reasons it was created and it will make your task much much simpler. Why try to re-invent the wheel?

Comment: okay... any sample for my scenario?

Comment: Why do you have all those `if()`? End result is they do nothing

Comment: my bad. didn't noticed that selection is working without `if` conditions.

Comment: but in real application based on toggle selection, I will show/hide some controls and do some initializations.  Agree to this plunker `if's` not needed. removing all if's

Answer (score 0):

I would use a directive for this. You can organize your button groups based on a common `ng-model` assignment.

You say not to refer you to third-party libraries, but the fact is that what you're describing been done already. If your goal is to learn, you can at least see how others have done it and do it your own way, though why re-invent the wheel?

I recommend that you refer to the source code for UI Bootstrap's button directives, specifically the `uib-btn-radio` directive. This does exactly what you've described.